# Separation with luxury vinyl plank flooring

Tags: flooring, vinyl

I put down this click lock type LVP.

So I’m starting to get a TINY bit of separation along the long edges of my LVP. It's only like this in a few places, the rest of the floor looks great. Is this something I need to worry about, or is this normal with LVP because of the hot/cold weather swing?

I'm worried my whole floor is gonna get messed up, but I think I may be overthinking it.

[image: Crack between floor planks]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Just how wide is this crack? (Looks to be inconsequential in the picture.)

Comment: Not large at all. None of them are really too large at all. I can’t see below them. I just didn’t know if it was the first sign of it coming apart lol

Comment: But seriously, how wide? A thickness of paper (which is about 0.004")? And, how many of these cracks are present across how wide a floor?

Comment: I would say the thickeness of two pieces of paper. Maybe a little less. The floor is 600 sq ft. One room is about 20 ft 15 ft. The other is about 20 ft by 10 ft. There’s only a few spaces like this. And it’s only on like one plank if that makes sense. Like on the picture....if you walk forward to the next plank, then the next plank doesn’t have anything wrong with it.

Comment: Is this click/ locked , glued, T&G style? To me the click locked flooring moves this much and it is not a problem, if glued it would be a problem.

Comment: It’s click lock.

Answer (score 1):

Such a minor amount of movement is, as you guessed, likely related to seasonal temperature swings. Vinyl does shrink and expand.

Comment: Knowing it is click lock I would expect some movement and would consider this normal.